# UITableViewCell.accessoryView will disappear in iOS 7

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, accessoryview

I assign some custom view to `UITableViewCell.accessoryView`， but if I scroll the tableView crazy, some `accessoryView` will disappear in iOS 7, and if I touch the cell, it's `accessoryView` can appear,  I don't know why, because it's correct in iOS 6. This is my code, someone can help me?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"CELL %d", (int)indexPath.row+1];

    NSDictionary * dict = [_dataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if ([dict objectForKey:@"switch"])
    {
        cell.accessoryView = [dict objectForKey:@"switch"];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryView = nil;
    }  

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When we use ReusableCellWithIdentifier in table view it reuse cells in table, you set **cell.accessoryView = nil;** it's remove accessory view for all cells in table view with same **CellIdentifier** try this code, it's solve your problem :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    NSDictionary * dict = [_dataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryView = [dict objectForKey:@"switch"];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"CELL %d", (int)indexPath.row+1];

    if ([dict objectForKey:@"switch"])
    {
        cell.accessoryView.hidden=NO;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryView.hidden=YES;
    }  
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this code doesn't work in iOS7 (Xcode5+iOS7 SDK+ iOS7 Simulator/iPhone), when I drag the table with big offset, some accessroyView will disappear as before :(

Comment: [dict objectForKey:@"switch"] is view ? add accessoryView code.

Comment: create uiswitch custom view when cell== nil, cell not use one switch in all views